# Perhaps the weirdest EXC_BAD_ACCESS I've seen Swift generate

Tags: swift, exc-bad-access, nszombie

I have a set of classes forming a decorator pattern so that I can do some layered caching. I have an abstract class which provides the core processing of images and contains a number of overridable functions where implementations can add their individual processing.

When saving an image I have the following code:

```
func cacheImage(_ key:String, image:UIImage?) {
    if let image = image {
        saveImage(key, image:image)
    } else {
        deleteImage(key)
    }
    backingCache?.cacheImage(key, image:image)
}

func saveImage(_ key:String, image:UIImage) {}

func deleteImage(_ key:String) {}
```

This is where it gets weird. When compiled for Release, this code will generate an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Tracing it with Zombies on shows messages being sent to UIImage instances after they have been deallocated.

If I attempt to get more information by compiling with the Debug configuration, the EXC_BAD_ACCESS stop occurring. Making it very difficult to debug.

I've found that if I add a `print(...)` statements like this:

```
func deleteImage(_ key:String) {
    print("Abstract delete image")
}
```

the EXC_BAD_ACCESS goes away.

My current theory is that without the `print(...)`, Swift is aggressively de-allocing the image instances. I also remember reading something about Debug delaying ARC's garbage collection which would explain why the EXC_BAD_ACCESS doesn't occur in debug.

I've also now found that changing the method signature to:

```
open func deleteImage(_ key:String) {}
```

Also removes the EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Can anyone give a more detailed explanation of why the EXC_BAD_ACCESS zombies are occurring? I can't see why in the first place.

Comment: Would be great if you could create a reduced project that only contains the bare minimum to exhibit the crash and share it. Then you could file a bug at https://bugs.swift.org (Or I'll do it for you if you like)

Comment: Try different setting for the `Optimization Level` build setting, to pinpoint the root of the issue.

Comment: I'm having this issue too [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48795609/i-am-getting-exc-bad-access-code-1-address-0x30-bad-access-even-when-object-e)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in my project when I was trying to set `@Published` var.
I have solved it by wrapping it with:

```swift
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
     // set the `@Published` var here
 }
```